# Pattern in even numbers of distinct prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> > **Question**
> >
> > let consider $p_0,p_1,p_2,...,p_{2r+1}$ are even distinct prime numbers.
> >
> > Then show that
> >
> > $$\sum_{i=0}^{r}p_{a_{2i}} p_{a_{2i+1}} -p_{b_{2i}} p_{b_{2i+1}}=\sum_{i=0}^{r}(p_{a_{2i}}-1)( p_{a_{2i+1}}-1)-(p_{b_{2i}}-1) (p_{b_{2i+1}}-1)$$
> >
> > Where $0\leq a_j,b_j\leq 2r+1$

**Example**

Let $(p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3)$ are $(5,47,2,3)$ respectively, so

$$ p_{a_{0}} p_{a_{1}} -p_{b_0} p_{b_{1}}+p_{a_{2}} p_{a_{3}} -p_{b_2} p_{b_{3}} $$

$$= 2×3-3×5+5×47-2×47  $$

$$=132$$

and

$$ (p_{a_{0}}-1) (p_{a_{1}}-1) -(p_{b_0}-1)( p_{b_{1}}-1)+(p_{a_{2}}-1)( p_{a_{3}}-1) -(p_{b_2}-1) (p_{b_{3}}-1) $$

$$= (2-1)(3-1)-(3-1)(5-1)+(5-1)(47-1)-(2-1)(47-1)  $$

$$=1×2-2×4+4×46-1×46$$

$$=132$$

Comment: Do you mean "an even number of distinct primes"?

Comment: Something goes wrong with the notation, I think. How do you choose the order of the minus signs, in order to get a positive result? .

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas There is $p_0$, so there is an even number of distinct primes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove the algebraic identity holds, not just for prime numbers.

Expand the RHS, what do you get?

$$\sum_{i=0}^{r}(p_{a_{2i}}-1)( p_{a_{2i+1}}-1)-(p_{b_{2i}}-1) (p_{b_{2i+1}}-1) \\
= \sum_{i=0}^{r}p_{a_{2i}} p_{a_{2i+1}} - p_{a_{2i}} - p_{a_{2i+1}} -p_{b_{2i}}p_{b_{2i+1}}+ p_{b_{2i}} + p_{b_{2i+1}}.$$